# How can I connect BigQuery to an Oracle Database with a fixed IP address?

Tags: oracle, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, ip-address, google-cloud-data-fusion

I need to extract data from an Oracle database to BigQuery, and my original idea is to use Data Fusion for this.

The owner of the Oracle database (an external partner) is asking me for a fixed IP address that will be able to access the data. As I'm not an expert, I'm having some trouble finding this info.

Which IP address should I give him? Where do I find this info? Should I [set up a private network](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/create-private-ip) for this?

The field "Private IP" is empty (disabled) when I create an instance in Data Fusion without configuring the VPC.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using Google Cloud Datastream to replicate data from Oracle to BigQuery.  For a secure connection, Datatsream supports securely tunneling traffic through a bastion host that has access to the Oracle database.  From the Oracle server, you'll allow connections from the Bastion host.  Datastream will connect to the bastion host encrypted over SSH.

Sample bastion host for Oracle setup:
https://github.com/cloud-jake/bortex/tree/main/sample-bastion